# Css code wrapping in Mozilla Firefox Style editor

Tags: css, firefox, word-wrap

Someone knows how to turn on wrapping of long css code in firefox style editor (developer tools)? For me it is important, because I make lon line for every css-rule. Thank you.

Comment: You can [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi), proposing to add this option maybe in "Editor Preferences" of "Toolbox Options".

Answer (score 0):

There's no Word Wrap setting for the Dev tools style editor.

However, you can enable Word Wrap if you View Source (Ctrl + U) by going to:

`View > Wrap Long Lines`

Comment: It doesn't exist yet unfortunately.

Comment: In the latest version of firefox (57) this option is no longer in the view menu but is available in the pop-up menu you get when you right click on the page.